# What is the R convention when plotting (e.g., for a scatterplot) if the data has missing values?

Tags: r, plot, missing-data

How does `R` treat missing values when plotting data?

For example, if I have data that I read in from a csv like the following:

```
Y    X1    X2
0.1  0.2   0.1
0.2  0.2
...
```

how would `R` treat that second observation when plotting (specifically for a scatterplot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be omitted. However the visual effect depends a lot on the type of chart you choose. Try with these:

```
x <- c(1,NA,3,5,2,4)
plot(x, t="l") #line
plot(x, t="p") #points
plot(x, t="b") #both
barplot(x)
```

I'd say `barplot` is the best way when plotting data that includes `NA`'s, but of course that's up to you.

see `help(plot)` or `help(barplot)` for details.

---

EDIT: with a scatterplot these would be omitted as well, see below

```
y <- 1:6
plot(x,y, t="p") #points
```

Comment: What would happen with a scatterplot?